# Looking for a regular expression solution

Tags: regex, perl

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches the first two specific fields (variable strings written in Perl). In a file a line without a comment `#` starts with any character, length unspecific followed by a whitespace and another nonspecific length string followed by a  whitespace: `name info data1 data2 data3`.

The following works for matching the second field only but I want the first two fields to match exactly: `/^[^#].*\s$INFO\s/` where `$INFO="info"`. I tried variations of the above to no avail. My first attempt was this: `/^[^#]$NAME\s$INFO\s/` which seemed logical to me if `$NAME="name"` for the above record.

Comment: give us an example of a full string and what you want from it.

Comment: It's in the post.   "name info data1 data2 data3" I only care about "name" and "info" to match, I don't care about the rest. But the first two fields will be variable alphanumaeric strings.

Comment: like this? I'm having trouble understanding what exactly the initial string is. \#{0}(\w*) (\w*) \w* \w* \w*

Comment: So basically what you need is to match the first 2 words that are not preceded with a `#` ?

Comment: That's a true statement HamZa. Basically I'm running a perl script that reads a common file and the first two fields represent the server name and a program instance and I'm looking to set some environment variables based on those two fields because two instances of this program could run on the same server but would have different environments which are the rest of the fields plus I could prevent some other server from running the same script with another server's environment. Just matching the instance field(the 2nd field) doesn't prevent that. Instance set by C/L option, server by program.

Comment: `if($line =~ /^[^#]$HOST\s$INST\s/)` is what I want to be true if the first two fields match $HOST and $INST variables. This doesn't work though. What works for the 2nd field match only is `if($line =~ /^[^#].*\s$INST\s/)` .

Answer (score 2):

> My first attempt was this: /^[^#]$NAME\s$INFO\s/

This won't work because (implied from the question) the character before `$NAME` is either `#` *or nothing*. As such you just need to remove that first `[^#]`:

```
/^$NAME\s$INFO\s/
```

Which will match the string:

```
"$NAME $INFO <whatever or nothing>"
```

Comment: I solved this by using a double test with two different regexes 




    `if($line =~ /^[^#].*\s$INST\s/  && $line =~ /^$HOST\s/)`



 The second one doesn't need to check for a comment character since the first already does. Thanks AD7six, when I wrote this 10yrs ago, I started with that but got worried about #. In my case it would always work since field1 was hostname and # is illegal. I wanted the admins to be able to comment out an entry. I'm revamping code now to use ssh and saw this and said 'ooh, that's not right' but the answer was too simple, and I over-thought it!

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not a regex expert, this may work (I also am not clear on the precise details of the question so I made some assumptions):

```
'$NAME=name #$INFO=info $DATA=data1 data2 data3'.replace(/#[\S]+/g,'').match(/\$[\S]+/g);
```

This returns an array. The first 2 elements are the 'fields' i.e. [0]='$NAME=name' AND [1]='$DATA=data1'

Hope that helps at all. And apologies to the gods for my regex.